# how to find top N descending values in group in dplyr

Tags: r

I have a following dataframe in R

```
  Serivce     Codes
   ABS         RT
   ABS         RT
   ABS         TY
   ABS         DR
   ABS         DR
   ABS         DR
   ABS         DR
   DEF         RT
   DEF         RT
   DEF         TY
   DEF         DR
   DEF         DR
   DEF         DR
   DEF         DR
   DEF         TY
   DEF         SE
   DEF         SE
```

What I want is service wise code count in descending order

```
  Serivce     Codes    Count
   ABS         DR        4
   ABS         RT        2 
   ABS         TY        1
   DEF         DR        4
   DEF         RT        2
   DEF         TY        2
```

I am doing following in r

```
df%>% 
group_by(Service,Codes) %>% 
summarise(Count = n()) %>%
top_n(n=3,wt = Count) %>% 
arrange(desc(Count)) %>% 
as.data.frame()
```

But,it does not give me what is intended.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can try with `count/arrange/slice`

```
df1 %>% 
   count(Service, Codes) %>%
   arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
   group_by(Service) %>% 
   slice(seq_len(3))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Service [2]
#  Service Codes     n
#    <chr> <chr> <int>
#1     ABS    DR     4
#2     ABS    RT     2
#3     ABS    TY     1
#4     DEF    DR     4
#5     DEF    RT     2
#6     DEF    SE     2
```

---

In the OP's code, we need to `arrange` by 'Service' too.  As @Marius said in the comments, the `top_n` will include more number of rows if there are ties.  One option is to do a second grouping with 'Service' and `slice` (as showed above) or after the grouping, we can `filter`

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Service,Codes) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  top_n(n=3,wt = Count)  %>%
  arrange(Service, desc(Count)) %>%
  group_by(Service) %>%
  filter(row_number() <=3)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I am just wondering why my approach is not working ?

Comment: @Neil Updated the post

Comment: @Neil You also get more than 3 rows per group in your original code because `top_n` includes more than `n` rows if there are ties.

Comment: @Neil As Marius said the ties is a problem there.  So u can add `df1 %>% group_by(Service,Codes) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>%top_n(n=3,wt = Count) %>% group_by(Service) %>% slice(seq_len(3))`

Answer (score 1):

df%>% count(Service,Codes) %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(n))) %>% filter(rank < 5)

## number of rows to return for top_n()  just like row_number()

## n is group by Service,Codes then count  like

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can do this in two lines.

```
# get data.frame of counts by service-code pairs
mydf <- data.frame(table(dat))

# get top 3 by service
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(mydf, mydf$Serivce), function(x) x[order(-x$Freq)[1:3],]))
```

This returns

```
      Serivce Codes Freq
ABS.1     ABS    DR    4
ABS.3     ABS    RT    2
ABS.7     ABS    TY    1
DEF.2     DEF    DR    4
DEF.4     DEF    RT    2
DEF.6     DEF    SE    2
```

In the first line use `table` to get the counts, then convert to data.frame. In the second line, split by service, order by the negative values of `order` and pull out the first three elements. Combine the results with `do.call`.